# How to write a stored procedure in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I am not able to find where to write the stored procedure in phpMyAdmin and how to call it using MVC architecture.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In phpMyAdmin you can create the stored procedure in the SQL window.

You may have to set the delimieter to something like "$$" instead of the default ";". You can change this from the bottom of the SQL window.

[image]

Also you can refer this: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx

Comment: You would need Use Call syntax. refer this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html  For example If you have a stored prcedure by name insert_loop, then you would have to use CALL `insert_loop`;

Answer (score 74):

You can easily create procedures in phpMyAdmin.

1. Go to your database. Click 'Routines' tab in header
2. Click on 'Add routine'

[image]

3. Then a popup window will be opened. In that write your procedure and
   click on "GO"

For example like follows.
[image]

That's it. You can view your created procedures under 'Routines' tab itself.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

you can create a stored procedure in the sql query window on the phpmyadmin as you write any other query. And as soon as you execute the SP, it will be stored in the database's information_schema. You can check the existence of SP by the following commands:

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS
SHOW FUNCTION STATUS
```

and

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE 
       ROUTINE_TYPE="PROCEDURE" 
   AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA="dbname"
;
```

Answer (score 0):

STORED PROCEDURES are written using normal SQL language in the SQL box available in `phpmyadmin->database->table->execute sql`

Refer this: - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html