# user defined functions returning multiple values in sql

Tags: sql

I have the following tables in sql :

[image]

I want to write an function that will take Student_ID as parameter and return the Student_Name and Balance from the above table.

How can I do that  ?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @osimerpothe I have posted an answer for sql-server...Check whether it is correct or not..

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `myproc`(IN `id` INT)
NO SQL
SELECT student.Student_Name, account.Balance 
FROM student INNER JOIN account
ON student.Student_ID = account.Student_ID
WHERE student.Student_ID = id
```

you can create procedure from phpmyadmin:
[How to write a stored procedure in phpMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481890/how-to-write-a-stored-procedure-in-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 1):

Function can be created as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION function_name(@Student_ID int)
RETURNS @name_and_balanceTable TABLE 
(
    -- Columns returned by the function_name
    Name nvarchar(50),
    Balance int
)
AS 
-- Returns the Name and Balance for particular Student_ID
BEGIN
    -- Selecting the name and balance
    SELECT 
        @Name = st.Student_Name, 
        @Balance = ac.Balance
    FROM Student st JOIN Account ac ON st.Student_ID = ac.Student_ID 
    WHERE st.Student_ID = @Student_ID;

    -- Insert these value into table
    BEGIN
        INSERT @name_and_balanceTable
        SELECT @Name, @Balance;
    END;
    RETURN;
END;
```

This is for sql-server.
For more information use [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx)...