# stored procedure in php mysql - phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, procedure

I would like to create a stored procedure in PHP MySQL via PHPMyAdmin. When I put this on as a SQL command:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getBanks() 
BEGIN
select * from cp_banks; END
```

I receive the following error:

> There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem
>
> ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 1
>   STR: //
>   SQL: //
>   CREATE PROCEDURE getBanks() 
>   BEGIN
>   select * from cp_banks;//
>   CREATE PROCEDURE getBanks() 
>   BEGIN
>   select * from cp_banks;//
>   CREATE PROCEDURE getBanks() 
>   BEGIN
>   select * from cp_banks;

MySQL said:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE getBanks()
>   BEGIN
>   select * from cp_banks' at line 1

Please tell me where the error comes from.

Comment: The error message complains about `//`, but I don't see that in your procedure. I think you're not showing us everything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a stored procedure using phpmyadmin and how to use it through php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846516/how-to-write-a-stored-procedure-using-phpmyadmin-and-how-to-use-it-through-php)

Comment: I presume you're using `//` as a delimiter? Have you defined this anywhere? I believe there is an input box where you can specify the delimiter in PHPMyAdmin near the bottom of the SQL Command window. Make sure you set the delimiter to `//` there.

Comment: It looks like you haven't defined the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the delimiter or call it before creating your procedure.

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE getBanks() 
BEGIN
    select * from cp_banks;
END//
```

Since you are using phpmyadmin, you should remove the delimiter line and set it in the GUI; https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfb8q.png

Comment: Now its give following error - "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//' at line 4"

Comment: @Sefam You're on the right track. I believe PHPMyAdmin has a delimiter input box though right below the SQL Command window. You should leave the SQL statement as is and simply define the delimiter in the specified input box.

Comment: Since you are using phpmyadmin, you should go in the sql tab and set the "Delimiter" field to //. Edit: Didn't see War10ck's response, pretty much what he said. remove the delimiter line and set it directly through the GUI; as shown here http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfb8q.png