# Can not execute sql statment to create procedure after copying text from a stored procedure on phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a procedure, it worked an hour ago and now it's throwing an error. I exported the procedure(copied a text statement phpmyadmin output for me) and it wont let me execute the code I exported. The exported code is below followed by the error report phpmyadmin is displaying.

Also, all the sql queries work on their own but when the procedure was being called before I exported it, it was running but the queries were not affecting any rows. Am I labeling the variables wrong or something?(I don't think I am, I did check)

What I entered:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `DeleteCard`(IN `@aName` VARCHAR(255))
NO SQL
BEGIN
UPDATE Decks 
JOIN Amount ON amount.DeckName = decks.DeckName 
SET decks.DeckTotal = Decks.DeckTotal - Decks.DeckTotal
WHERE Amount.AmountName = @aName;

UPDATE Types t1
JOIN Cards ON cards.TypeName = t1.TypeName 
JOIN Amount ON amount.CardName = Cards.CardName
SET t1.TypeTotal = t1.TypeTotal - Amount.Amount
WHERE Amount.CardName = @aName;

DELETE  
FROM Amount 
WHERE CardName = @aName;


DELETE  
FROM Cards 
WHERE CardName = aName;
END
```

Error report:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `DeleteCard`(IN `aName` VARCHAR(255))
NO SQL
BEGIN
UPDATE Decks 
JOIN Amount ON amount.DeckName = decks.DeckName 
SET decks.DeckTotal = Decks.DeckTotal - Decks.DeckTotal
WHERE Amount.AmountName = aName;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a stored procedure using phpmyadmin and how to use it through php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846516/how-to-write-a-stored-procedure-using-phpmyadmin-and-how-to-use-it-through-php)

Comment: You either need to change the delimiter so that the first `;` is not interpreted as the end of the procedure, or use the dedicated stored routine interface.

Answer (score 0):

In the last delete query, you're missing `@` before variable name:

```
DELETE  
FROM Cards 
WHERE CardName = aName; -- should be @aName
```

Also, remove the

```
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
```

from your procedure, if you have any intentions to access your database remotely ever.

Comment: Hey again Shaharyar, I added the @ symbol but it is still throwing the same error at the same pice of the code. Line 7, that is the line that reads "WHERE Amount.AmountName = @aName;"

Comment: Are you running this complete script as an statement? If yes, then please do use phpmyadmin GUI to create it. Besides, all queries look fine except `lowercase` and `uppercase` table names somewhere.

Comment: I used phpmyadmin to create the statement, then I re uploaded the database, like a tool. i copied back in the statement to the new database and here I am... Editing the names didn't change anything.