# Mysql Select Last inserted row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I'm creating a stored procedure using phpmyadmin for mysql 5.5.55 .

```
INSERT INTO drama_ (value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6)
VALUES (val1,val2,0,0,0,0);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

but i'm getting a syntax error in `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`

EDIT :

```
You have an error your SQL syntax: check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()' at line 4
```

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Comment: You probably forgot to use a `DELIMITER` statement before defining the procedure.

Comment: @Barmar i'm using phpmyadmin GUI to create my statement wich gives you an interface where you select your parameters , note that the first statement works perfectly

Comment: @DarshanMehta You have an error ...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the syntax of the second statement. So the problem must be with how you're defining the stored procedure.

Comment: @aureliaLobianco Post the whole error message in the question. We need to see the "near" part of it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846516/how-to-write-a-stored-procedure-using-phpmyadmin-and-how-to-use-it-through-php. You need to change the Delimiter field in the SQL tab of PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: @Barmar that didnt works since i'm not using the SQL tab to create my stored proc

Comment: Are you using the "Routines" tab, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20869749/1491895)?

Comment: @Barmar Yes sir

Comment: I suggest you use the SQL tab, it sounds like a PhpMyAdmin issue. I don't use it, so I don't know the solution.