# How to create stored procedure in phpmyadmin but I got error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

```
INSERT INTO cash_flows (`start_balance`,`end_balance`, `transaction_amount`, `transaction_type`,`customer_register_id`,`note`) 
SELECT promo_balance, 0.00 , promo_balance, 'promo_expired', id,'promotion is expired' 
FROM `customer_registers` 
WHERE `promo_expire_date` < CURDATE();

UPDATE `customer_registers` 
SET `promo_balance`= 0.00 
WHERE `promo_expire_date` < CURDATE();
```

[stored procedure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajJNe.png)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE customer_registers SET promo_balance= 0.00 WHERE promo_expire_date < CURD' at line 4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846516/how-to-write-a-stored-procedure-using-phpmyadmin-and-how-to-use-it-through-php