# Can't save a stored procedure: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a `stored procedure` in `phpmyadmin`.

My definition is:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `medication_mapping` (`patient_id`, `active_ingredient_id`, `strength`, `pharmaceutical_dose_form_id`, `number_of_units_per_intake`, `frequency_of_intake`, `date_of_onset`, `duration`, `unit_id`, `status`, `version_id`) VALUES (p_id, a_i_id, str, dose_id, n_u, freq, onset_dt, duration, unit_id, stat, v_id);
END
```

When I'm trying to save it I get the following message:

```
One or more errors have occurred while processing your request:
The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`cefcy`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_medication_mapping`(IN `p_id` INT(11), ) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN INSERT INTO `medication_mapping` (`patient_id`, `active_ingredient_id`, `strength`, `pharmaceutical_dose_form_id`, `number_of_units_per_intake`, `frequency_of_intake`, `date_of_onset`, `duration`, `unit_id`, `status`, `version_id`) VALUES (p_id, a_i_id, str, dose_id, n_u, freq, onset_dt, duration, unit_id, stat, v_id); END"
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN INSERT INTO `medication_m' at line 1
```

This is my `medication_mapping` table:

[image]

This is how my edit routine dialog shows:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know in phpMyAdmin, you got to define the entire procedure including delimiters. I personally never add them via myadmin though.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_medication_mapping()
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO `medication_mapping` (`patient_id`, `active_ingredient_id`, `strength`, `pharmaceutical_dose_form_id`, `number_of_units_per_intake`, `frequency_of_intake`, `date_of_onset`, `duration`, `unit_id`, `status`, `version_id`) 
        VALUES (p_id, a_i_id, str, dose_id, n_u, freq, onset_dt, duration, unit_id, stat, v_id);
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

What version are you using? There might be some differences. 
[Walkthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846516/how-to-write-a-stored-procedure-using-phpmyadmin-and-how-to-use-it-through-php)